# add item just below the selected items from the nested list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a nested list with collapse feature. Everything is working but i need to add the content just below the selected item when i click on add button. For example, in the demo i have attached, there you will see the nested list. If i select the Level 1 c, and click on add button the new item should be added just beneath that selected item. How can i do it so? Can anyone share me the idea, please? I am struggling to even understand how the item will be exactly shown just below the selected item.

Here is what I have done

NestedList.js

```
const renderChildren = (dropHandler, isExpanded) => item => (
  <React.Fragment key={item.slug}>
    <ListItem
      key={item.slug}
      dataattr={item.slug}
    >
      {"children" in item ? (
        <StyledListItem
          color="var(--secondary)"
          primary={`${item.title} - done`}
        />
      ) : (
        <StyledNavLink to="/">
          <StyledListItem
            color="var(--secondary)"
            primary={`${item.title} - done`}
          />
        </StyledNavLink>
      )}

      {"children" in item && <ExpandMore onClick={() => dropHandler(item.slug)} />}
    </ListItem>
    {"children" in item && (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Collapse in={isExpanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
          <List component="div">
            <NestedList items={item.children} />
          </List>
        </Collapse>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
  </React.Fragment>
);

class NestedList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isExpanded: false
  };

  dropHandler = () => this.setState({ isExpanded: !this.state.isExpanded });

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;

    if (!items) return null; // Don't render when it shouldn't

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {items.map(renderChildren(this.dropHandler, this.state.isExpanded))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default NestedList;
```

Here is the demo

https://codesandbox.io/s/p3qx6pq3z0

Update

I could show the input field beneath the selected items and could also add the items but only for the first level it works not for the nested ones.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vn1qr3wqm5

Comment: Can you not insert the new item into the `children` array of the selected item at the first index?

Comment: yes i can but only for the first level not for the nested one. I could not.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting objects at a given position in an array can in JavaScript be done with splice, afterwards rerender and you're done!

```
var list = ["foo", "bar"];
list.splice( 1, 0, "baz"); // position to place new object, delete objects count, object to insert

["foo", "baz", "bar"] // result
```

You know the index to insert based on position of insert button...

Comment: can you show just dummy text in the demo i have provided, please?

Comment: I have no experience with React yet, only with React Native which is similar... I see that I misread your question a little bit: you should place the selected index in the state, then when pressing your add button add an object of your choice to the array. (I tought you had a add button for each element on which you could click... nevertheless the principle remains the same!)

Comment: I could add in the items which is at first level but not inside deep level. Can you check it this, please?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vn1qr3wqm5

Comment: When I select a deeper level it still seems works in the link you provided? 
If you have a normal tree with 'children' on each level, you can store an array of ids to insert the item at the correct child on any level in the array (that is what you mean?). For example: you want to insert an item below the second item on level2, under the first level1 element then you store [0,1] as index array. When you add an item you loop over the provided indexes and insert when no more indexes are left in the array. Some kind of recursive function might be your best solution to handle this I think.